# Getting issues Running Apache Pheonix on hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hbase

After installing Apache Pheonix and following all the steps as per the official documentattion ,and after starting the hbbase process I can see all the pocesses running as seen:

[image: jps]

[image: On trying to test Pheonix:]
On trying to test Pheonix:

This would stay for a couple of minutes after which exceptions would be thrown.

Exception, re-throwing exception org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionLossException` can happen for a million reasons. The most likely of which is a query timeout.

Unfortunately, phoenix has a steep learning curve, like HBase. You're not going to be able to just query whatever you want like you would in MySQL and have it return results. The job is on the query writer to write very, very efficient queries.

Try using the ROWKEY for the table to get your query to return in a timely manner. For instance, in our tables, our ROWKEY includes a very familiarly-structured ID in the beginning. So I know that if I run a query like this:

```
select count(*) from "table" where ROWKEY like '0%' and "bla" = '123';
```

that in my particular table I'm going to get 10% of the table's results back in my count. So I just multiply my count by 10.

To start, try the following query:

```
select ROWKEY from "table" limit 1;
```

If that returns, then you know I'm right and your job from there is to write very, very efficient, limited-result queries.

One other thing you can try: extend the timeouts via your hbase-site.xml. Here's is my client-side hbase-site.xml that I use with phoenix:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
    <value>1000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>1800000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.query.threadPoolSize</name>
    <value>768</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.query.queueSize</name>
    <value>15000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.query.keepAliveMs</name>
    <value>300000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.connection.autoCommit</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.schema.dropMetaData</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.sequence.saltBuckets</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

These settings will allow you to write slightly less-efficient queries.